# Document Classification using Naive Bayes classifier

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, bayesian-networks, document-classification

I am making a document classifier in mahout using the simple naive bayes algorithm. Currently, 98% of the data(documents) I have is of Class A and only 2% is of class B. My question is, since there is such a wide gap in the percentage of Class A docs vs Class B docs, would the classifier be able to train accurately still?

What I'm thinking of doing is ignoring a whole bunch of Class A documents and "manipulating" the dataset I have so that there isn't such a wide gap in the composition of the documents. Thus, the dataset I'll end up having will consist 30% of Class B and 70% of Class A. But, are there any repercussions of doing that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not necessarily sample dataset A to reduce its instances. Several methods are available for efficient learning from imbalanced datasets, such as Majority Undersampling (exactly what you did), Minority Oversampling, SMOTE, and etc. Here is an empirical comparison of these methods: http://machinelearning.org/proceedings/icml2007/papers/62.pdf

Alternatively, you may define a custom cost matrix for the classifier. In other words, assuming B=Positive class, you may define cost(False Positive) < cost(False Negative). In this case, the classifier's output will bias towards the positive class. Here is a very helpful tutorial: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.164.4418&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 2):

A lot of this gets into how good "accuracy" is as a measure of performance, and that depends on your problem. If misclassifying "A" as "B" is just as bad/ok as misclassifying "B" as "A", then there is little reason to do anything other than just mark everything as "A", since you know it will reliably get you a 98% accuracy (so long as that unbalanced distribution is representative of the true distribution).

Without knowing your problem (and if accuracy is the measure you should use), the best answer I could give is "it depends on the data set". It is possible that you could get past 99% accuracy with standard naive bays, though it may be unlikely. For Naive Bayes in particular, one thing you could do is to disable the use of priors (the prior is essentially the proportion of each class). This has the effect of pretending that every class is equally likely to occur, though the model parameters will have been learned from uneven amounts of data.

Your proposed solution is a common practice, it sometimes works well. Another practice is to create fake data for the smaller class (how would depend on your data, for text documents I'm not aware of any particularly good way). Another practice is to increase the weights of the data points in the under-represented classes.

You can search for "imbalanced classification" and find a lot more information about these types of problems (they are one of the harder ones).

If accuracy is not actually a good measure for your problem, you can search for more information about "cost sensitive classification" which should be helpful.